# Material design - Calender alignment insider a card-reveal module

Tags: css, datepicker, material-design

I have been working on a Material design web layout to create a dashboard for my application. I am using a card reveal module to display a form field where user will be able to update his/her date of birth. For this I am using material design date picker inside the card reveal box But I am seeing the calender appearing and confining its position only inside card reveal. Anyone saw this problem? Any thoughts?

[image]

**Adding Code**

```
<div class="col s12 m12 l6 right">
                                <!--code for displaying employee details-->
                                <div id="profile-card" class="card" style="overflow: hidden;">
                                    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                                        <img class="activator" src="assets/images/_userbg.jpg" alt="user background"><span class="dddd_client_name card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Chethan Kumar</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-content">
                                        <img src="assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="" class="circle responsive-img activator card-profile-image">
                                        <a class="btn-floating activator btn-move-up waves-effect waves-light light-blue accent-3 right">
                                            <i class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
                                            <div class="col s12 m6 l6 dddd_client_detail">
                                                <i class="btn-floating mdi mdi-account-card-details white-text text-darken-2"></i> <span>Emp ID: 1234567</span>  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col s12 m6 l6 dddd_client_detail">
                                                <i class="btn-floating mdi mdi-phone white-text text-darken-2"></i> <span>+91 999 999 9999</span>  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col s12 m6 l6 dddd_client_detail">
                                                <i class="btn-floating mdi mdi-account white-text text-darken-2"></i> <span>Male</span>  
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col s12 m6 l6 dddd_client_detail">
                                                <i class="btn-floating mdi mdi-cake-variant white-text text-darken-2"></i> <span>01/07/1989</span>  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col s12 m12 l12 dddd_client_detail">
                                                <i class="btn-floating mdi mdi-email-outline white-text text-darken-2"></i> <span>mail@domain.com</span>  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col s12 m6 l6 dddd_client_detail hide">
                                                <i class="btn-floating mdi mdi-account white-text text-darken-2"></i> <span>Band: H &amp; Below</span>  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col s12 m6 l6 dddd_client_detail hide">
                                                <i class="btn-floating mdi mdi-currency-inr white-text text-darken-2"></i> <span>Sum Insured: 2,00,000</span>  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col s12 m12 l12 dddd_client_detail hide">
                                                <i class="btn-floating mdi mdi-clock white-text text-darken-2"></i> <span>Coverage Inception Date: 07/11/2016</span>  
                                            </div>
                                        </div>



                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-reveal" id="empformcard" style="display: block; transform: translateY(-100%);">
                                        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4"><i class="mdi mdi-close right"></i></span>

                                        <h4 class="client_edit_title">You can edit your details here.</h4>
                                        <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
                                            <form id="edit_profile" class="col s12 m12 l12 form-validate">
                                                <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12">
                                                    <i class="mdi mdi-phone prefix"></i>
                                                    <input id="dob" type="date" class="validate datepicker picker__input picker__input--active" required="" readonly="" tabindex="-1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" aria-readonly="false" aria-owns="username_root"><div class="picker picker--focused picker--opened" id="username_root" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false"><div class="picker__holder"><div class="picker__frame"><div class="picker__wrap"><div class="picker__box"><div class="picker__date-display"><div class="picker__weekday-display">Tuesday</div><div class="picker__month-display"><div>Dec</div></div><div class="picker__day-display"><div>20</div></div><div class="picker__year-display"><div>2016</div></div></div><div class="picker__calendar-container"><div class="picker__header"><select class="picker__select--month browser-default" aria-controls="username_table" title="Select a month"><option value="0">January</option><option value="1">February</option><option value="2">March</option><option value="3">April</option><option value="4">May</option><option value="5">June</option><option value="6">July</option><option value="7">August</option><option value="8">September</option><option value="9">October</option><option value="10">November</option><option value="11" selected="">December</option></select><select class="picker__select--year browser-default" aria-controls="username_table" title="Select a year"><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2014">2014</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016" selected="">2016</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2018">2018</option><option value="2019">2019</option><option value="2020">2020</option><option value="2021">2021</option><option value="2022">2022</option><option value="2023">2023</option></select><div class="picker__nav--prev" data-nav="-1" role="button" aria-controls="username_table" title="Previous month"> </div><div class="picker__nav--next" data-nav="1" role="button" aria-controls="username_table" title="Next month"> </div></div><table class="picker__table" id="username_table" role="grid" aria-controls="username" aria-readonly="true"><thead><tr><th class="picker__weekday" scope="col" title="Sunday">S</th><th class="picker__weekday" scope="col" title="Monday">M</th><th class="picker__weekday" scope="col" title="Tuesday">T</th><th class="picker__weekday" scope="col" title="Wednesday">W</th><th class="picker__weekday" scope="col" title="Thursday">T</th><th class="picker__weekday" scope="col" title="Friday">F</th><th class="picker__weekday" scope="col" title="Saturday">S</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--outfocus" data-pick="1480185000000" role="gridcell" aria-label="27 November, 2016">27</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--outfocus" data-pick="1480271400000" role="gridcell" aria-label="28 November, 2016">28</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--outfocus" data-pick="1480357800000" role="gridcell" aria-label="29 November, 2016">29</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--outfocus" data-pick="1480444200000" role="gridcell" aria-label="30 November, 2016">30</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1480530600000" role="gridcell" aria-label="1 December, 2016">1</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1480617000000" role="gridcell" aria-label="2 December, 2016">2</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1480703400000" role="gridcell" aria-label="3 December, 2016">3</div></td></tr><tr><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1480789800000" role="gridcell" aria-label="4 December, 2016">4</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1480876200000" role="gridcell" aria-label="5 December, 2016">5</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1480962600000" role="gridcell" aria-label="6 December, 2016">6</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1481049000000" role="gridcell" aria-label="7 December, 2016">7</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1481135400000" role="gridcell" aria-label="8 December, 2016">8</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1481221800000" role="gridcell" aria-label="9 December, 2016">9</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1481308200000" role="gridcell" aria-label="10 December, 2016">10</div></td></tr><tr><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1481394600000" role="gridcell" aria-label="11 December, 2016">11</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1481481000000" role="gridcell" aria-label="12 December, 2016">12</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1481567400000" role="gridcell" aria-label="13 December, 2016">13</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1481653800000" role="gridcell" aria-label="14 December, 2016">14</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1481740200000" role="gridcell" aria-label="15 December, 2016">15</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1481826600000" role="gridcell" aria-label="16 December, 2016">16</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1481913000000" role="gridcell" aria-label="17 December, 2016">17</div></td></tr><tr><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1481999400000" role="gridcell" aria-label="18 December, 2016">18</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1482085800000" role="gridcell" aria-label="19 December, 2016">19</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus picker__day--today picker__day--highlighted" data-pick="1482172200000" role="gridcell" aria-label="20 December, 2016" aria-activedescendant="true">20</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1482258600000" role="gridcell" aria-label="21 December, 2016">21</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1482345000000" role="gridcell" aria-label="22 December, 2016">22</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1482431400000" role="gridcell" aria-label="23 December, 2016">23</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1482517800000" role="gridcell" aria-label="24 December, 2016">24</div></td></tr><tr><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1482604200000" role="gridcell" aria-label="25 December, 2016">25</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1482690600000" role="gridcell" aria-label="26 December, 2016">26</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1482777000000" role="gridcell" aria-label="27 December, 2016">27</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1482863400000" role="gridcell" aria-label="28 December, 2016">28</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1482949800000" role="gridcell" aria-label="29 December, 2016">29</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1483036200000" role="gridcell" aria-label="30 December, 2016">30</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1483122600000" role="gridcell" aria-label="31 December, 2016">31</div></td></tr><tr><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--outfocus" data-pick="1483209000000" role="gridcell" aria-label="1 January, 2017">1</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--outfocus" data-pick="1483295400000" role="gridcell" aria-label="2 January, 2017">2</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--outfocus" data-pick="1483381800000" role="gridcell" aria-label="3 January, 2017">3</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--outfocus" data-pick="1483468200000" role="gridcell" aria-label="4 January, 2017">4</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--outfocus" data-pick="1483554600000" role="gridcell" aria-label="5 January, 2017">5</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--outfocus" data-pick="1483641000000" role="gridcell" aria-label="6 January, 2017">6</div></td><td role="presentation"><div class="picker__day picker__day--outfocus" data-pick="1483727400000" role="gridcell" aria-label="7 January, 2017">7</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="picker__footer"><button class="btn-flat picker__today" type="button" data-pick="1482172200000" aria-controls="username">Today</button><button class="btn-flat picker__clear" type="button" data-clear="1" aria-controls="username">Clear</button><button class="btn-flat picker__close" type="button" data-close="true" aria-controls="username">Close</button></div></div></div></div></div></div> 
                                                    <label for="dob" class="">Phone</label>
                                                </div> 
                                                <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12 savebox">
                                                    <button type="submit" id="save_profile" class="btn tooltipped waves-effect waves-light col s12 m12 dddd_logbtn" data-position="left" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Click here to save" data-tooltip-id="c6e38560-2469-0651-3cc1-511059fe4b63">Save <i class="mdi mdi-content-save"></i></button>

                                                    <div class="lgauthload">

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your code or JSfiddle demo?

Comment: @SanjeevK I have added my code

Comment: can you post the working demo in JSfiddle with CSS and JS altogether?